# A cloud-based security/alarm/access control solution

Tags: home-security

I'd like to know if anyone knows of a decent, internet-connected alarm and access control system with modern software, possibly cloud-based or hybrid (on-site controller but it in turn talks to the cloud).

Requirements:

- good-looking and easy to use client software, web-based if possible
- excellent security and frequent updates, no backdoors nor hardcoded passwords
- works over IP and the Internet
- remote or cloud-based management
- motion-triggered alarm
- access control based on secure keycards (Mifare DESFire or equivalent crypto)
- should scale to hundreds of doors locks and motion sensors
- should not be like designed by idiots like [some alarm systems currently in use](http://cybergibbons.com/security-2/csl-dualcom-cs2300-signalling-unit-vulnerabilities/)

Price isn't an issue, I'm happy to pay good money for a reliable and future-proof system.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Topaz (GE) for many years and was pretty strong.  That brand has been acquired by Interlogix and they have since discontinued it for [TruPortal.](http://www.interlogix.com/access/brand/truportal)

It meets all of your  points with the exception of the first (good looking) and the last (not designed by idiots); those are purely subjective and impossible to quantify.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't fit the bill, I see no mention on how the thing actually works, how it talks to the app (is it even using HTTPS?) and what the keycards are (they will most likely be trivial to clone, thus I may as well leave the door open).

Comment: You have to talk to a sales rep.  They keep all the juicy details off their website.  I know that their old software only communicated via HTTPS so it's more than likely their new stuff will.  I used HID prox cards and those worked perfectly.  Don't make assumptions until you actually get the full specs.